# Is there a reason for which one should not add all the imports inside .pch file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm mainly refering to application-level imports, not when you build a library, in which case is obvious why you should avoid importing the headers inside the .pch file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the `.pch` file is that it can be precompiled once and left alone.

If you import all of your application headers in the `.pch`, it has to be recompiled every time you change any one of those headers, negating all of the benefits. Worse yet, this ends up meaning that every *other* file in your project has to be rebuilt, because the contents of the `.pch` changed.

The only headers that should be pulled in by your `.pch` are headers that'll almost never change, like system headers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all of your imports to the pch might make your build slower. It really depends on the project.

Let's say you have 100 .m files, and one of them uses AVFoundation.  If you add the AVFoundation header to your pch, then the compiler has to deal with the larger pch for every .m file, but only one of them benefits from it.  This might be slower or it might not. It's probably too small a difference to measure easily.

If you are thinking of adding your project's own .h files to the pch, that will definitely make your build slower, because Xcode will recompile every .m file when any one of your .h files changes.

Another reason to include a framework header only where it's needed is to make your source files easier to reuse if you decide to copy them to another project.